# How to wrap a HTML tag around placeholders using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

My input text looks like this:

```
something [something] some text [other] some [other] text
```

It contains "placeholders" that are wrapped in square brackets and I want to wrap them in html   tags.

The output should look like this:

```
something <b>[something]</b> some text <b>[other]</b> some <b>[other]</b> text
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following regex replacement:

```js
var input = "something [something] some text [other] some [other] text";
var output = input.replace(/(\[.*?\])/g, "<b>$1</b>");
console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```